# How to secure data or row ids that represents something in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

In my project a user can make a post (post a photo or some text). Technically I identify each post with a unique id in table **posts**  where I store the user_id (owener of the post) and the  id of the post is set to **auto increment** . Knowing the identification for each post I fetch all rows in the **post table** and put these post and relevant details( post_id, user_id, data, etc) inside an HTML. There are more things a user can do on that post, like discuss on the post, rate the post, and etc.

These things are done via an ajax post since I store the post_id on the HTML element attribute like ( **data-p=52**). sometimes I use the php **base64_encode** function to encrypt the **post_id**

Most in my application an event is acted on these  **post_id and user_id** that is or are stored in the HTML custom attributes.

Now I am thinking of security issues and my question is : Is there a proper method or way I can hold these info in Javascript or a proper way I can encrypt these information about the post.

Comment: What is your specific concern related to users being aware of these id values?

Comment: I am thinking an attacker could just use these ids to harm my database. Is that possible ?

Comment: Not with just the IDs. What they can do is easily increment / decrement them since they are simple integers. A simple solution would be to instead use UUIDs as your primary keys, in which case no one can guess what the 'next' one in the sequence is.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if someone sees the id you use to internally store your data as long as they can't access information they shouldn't even if they know the id. This is why good authentication protection is needed. Whenever you receive a request you should be able to tell that it's coming from a genuine authenticated user and figure out what permissions that user has.

Comment: hhmmmm...okay...am really learning from your answer

Comment: *"sometimes I use the php base64_encode function to encrypt the post_id"* – base64 encoding does not *encrypt* a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is good you are thinking about the possible security vulnerabilities within your system. However, at the moment, from what I can tell, you are not quite worrying about the right thing. Data, like a user's ID, a post's ID, is not sensitive in itself. If you look at the URL of social networks, etc, it is very likely you will see user ID information, etc. What you need to think about, is *how can I make sure that it doesn't matter this data is public?* In other words, how can I prevent an attacker from using this data? Because this data on it's own, is just a bunch of numbers. Now, if there is a reason why these IDs are actually sensitive in your system, you should think about a slight structural rearrangement.

Take the common (or less so these days) SQL Injection technique. Where a attacker will input SQL code into a user input, and that input will then be concatenated/substituted right into a SQL query, therefore giving unwanted access to the database (see here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). It does not matter the attacker knows the post ID, meaning *oh no! He can delete the post he wants to*, instead, it matters that he can delete any post he wants. So the problem is in the SQL vulnerability, not the knowing of the ID. And, to fix the SQL vulnerbabilty, you need to make sure that user input will disallow code-like characters. This is known as sanitization.

Of course I am not saying you shouldn't take care of what data is available to users. But **the system itself** needs to be robust.

Comment: i see...could an attacker send queries base on these ids?

Comment: Just updated my answer. Hope it helps. Do ask if you have further confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you're worried about (that an attacker can use these IDs to send requests to your system to manipulate data in a way that you don't want) is independent of whether you expose your IDs to the client or not.

In some fashion, requests from your client will need to be handled by your server. If you have a feature where authors of posts can delete their own posts, hopefully you are validating delete requests that the user initiating the request is actually the owner of that post and not just blindly deleting data whenever someone asks your system to.  Even if you introduced a surrogate key so as to prevent the actual primary key from leaking to the public, whatever route endpoint that is used to delete posts will still need to handle *that* data in a robust fashion that maintains the integrity of your data.

As I stated in a comment, really the only thing you should worry about are people performing maths on your IDs (such as plus and minus 1) in order to see if they can game your system and receive data back that maybe they shouldn't have.  But even in that scenario whatever endpoint is responding to the request should validate that request before returning anything back.  You can prevent this entirely by a) validating that the user requesting the data actually owns the data and b) by *not* using auto incremented integers as a primary key and instead relying on UUIDs as your primary keys.

Comment: I just googled about UUIDs. about 128 bit of code.. please do you have a link on how to use them?

Comment: Sure, [here](http://www.developerfiles.com/using-uuid-as-primary-key-in-mysqlmariadb-databases/) is a pretty good example showing how to set up a table to use a UUID as a primary key.